# add labels to sklearn k-means

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use kmeans in python.

```
data = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,0,3,2,4],[4,3,234,5,5],[23,4,5,1,4],[23,5,2,3,5]]
```

Each of this data have a label. Example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5] -> Fiat1
[1,0,3,2,4] -> Fiat2
[4,3,234,5,5] -> Mercedes
[23,4,5,1,4] -> Opel
[23,5,2,3,5] -> bmw

kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=3, n_init=10)
kmeans.fit(data)
```

My objective is after I run the KMeans, I want to obtain the labels of each cluster.

A fake example:

Cluster 1:
Fiat1,
Fiat2

Cluster 2:
Mercedes

Cluster 3:
bmw,
Opel

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Code

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,0,3,2,4],[4,3,234,5,5],[23,4,5,1,4],[23,5,2,3,5]])
labels = np.array(['Fiat1', 'Fiat2', 'Mercedes', 'Opel', 'BMW'])
N_CLUSTERS = 3

kmeans = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=N_CLUSTERS, n_init=10)
kmeans.fit(data)
pred_classes = kmeans.predict(data)

for cluster in range(N_CLUSTERS):
    print('cluster: ', cluster)
    print(labels[np.where(pred_classes == cluster)])
```

#### Output:

```
cluster:  0
['Opel' 'BMW']
cluster:  1
['Mercedes']
cluster:  2
['Fiat1' 'Fiat2']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put your labels in an array:

```
labels=['Fiat1', 'Fiat2', 'Mercedes', 'Opel', 'bmw']
```

Then,

```
n_clusters=3
pred_clusters=kmeans.fit(data).labels_
cluster_labels=[[] for i in range(n_clusters)]
for i, j in enumerate(pred_clusters):
    cluster_labels[j].append(labels[i])
```

will give you:

```
[['Fiat1', 'Fiat2'], ['Mercedes'], ['Opel', 'bmw']]
```

which is a list of data labels in each cluster.